# How to change button background as a progress?

Tags: android, xml, animation, button, view

I'm trying to change the background of a button as a "loading" while it's pressed, but I'm not sure how to make.

First I tried to use a progress bar but, what I want is to load the background progressively if the button is pressed or revert it if the button is released.

Thanks in advance for any idea.

Answer (score 1):

Set the button background to a selector, such as this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loading" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" android:state_focused="true" />
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
    <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

That should change the button background as you press and release the button.